# Go: Cast type fails for map[string]interface{} to map[string]string

Tags: casting, go

I wasn't sure why the following casting doesn't work:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    v := map[string]interface{}{"hello": "world"}
    checkCast(v)

}

func checkCast(v interface{}) {
    _, isCorrectType := v.(map[string]string)
    if !isCorrectType { 
        fmt.Printf("incorrect type")  <------------- why does it enter this if statement?
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

---

`map[string]interface{}` is not the same as `map[string]string`. Type `interface{}` is not the same as type `string`.

If they are both `map[string]string`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    v := map[string]string{"hello": "world"}
    checkCast(v)

}

func checkCast(v interface{}) {
    _, isCorrectType := v.(map[string]string)
    if !isCorrectType {
        fmt.Printf("incorrect type")
        return
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[no output]
```

---

The statement `v.(map[string]string)` is a type assertion, not a cast.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression `x` of interface type and a type `T`, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of
>   type `T`. The notation `x.(T)` is called a type assertion.

---

Go has conversions.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and
>   `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.

Comment: is there a way to cast in Go?

Comment: @Karan: See my revised answer. Go has conversions.